# Error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in angular 2 application

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am creating an basic application in angular 2 from which i will get the yahoo weather report by typing the city and state. On submitting the form, I am getting an error like

```
GET https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.for…2C%20%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in zone.js file.
```

I suppose the error is due to which i am using a third party tool. Is that right?? Please provide a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: connection reset can be a internet conenction error too..

Comment: I think in this case, that is not the error..

Comment: you face this on other websites too ? where is the app running ? localhost or on a web server

Comment: running this on localhost

Comment: I also had this problem : I was using an Ubuntu VM, and wasn't able to make PATCH requests from my computer. I've never found out the problem, but I corrected it by using windows (without VM) instead of my VM.